# How do i create a controller for ajax requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i want to create a controller that has actions will responds only for ajax requests. i have tried the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute but this stopped all ajax calls. So is there away to create a class with actions for ajax only?

secondly are there any precautions when creating such class?

Comment: You should create an `ApiController` for these tasks. http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-web-api-routes-and-apicontroller

Comment: @Ruslan so there aren't anyways to block the call to an Ajax action from typing it on address bar from MVC restrictions?

Comment: @PhillGreggan There is. You need to restrict it to accept `POST` requests only, which can be done with an attribute `[HttpPost]` or a handful of similar ones. You will then also need to make sure that your *front-end* issues `POST` instead of `GET` AJAX calls. However, while this will definitely prevent the user from typing it in their browser, there are other ways to fake `POST` requests using more sophisticated tools, if the user is tech-savvy and very determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To talk about the problem you have there is no direct method/attribute which can only respond to ajax request only.However you can create your own attribute which will respond to ajax request.

In MVC ajax request can be intercepted with `Request.IsAjaxRequest()`

Here is a code snippet:

```
public class isAjaxAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute 
{
    public override bool IsValidRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

Now you can use this attribute on your controller method like

```
[isAjax]
public ActionResult ajaxMethod()
{

}
```